# LLVM pointer as a function parameter

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to pass a global variable to a function as a parameter and modify this variable inside of a function

i have IR code as follows

```
@n = common global i32 0

declare i32 @readln(i32)

declare i32 @writeln(i32)

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %n = load i32, i32* @n, align 4
  %calltmp = call i32 @readln(i32 %n)
  %n1 = load i32, i32* @n, align 4
  %calltmp2 = call i32 @writeln(i32 %n1)
  ret i32 0
}
```

readln defined in separate module as a C function

```
int readln(int * x) {
    return  scanf("%d", x);
}
```

upon running i get `segmentation fault 11`
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You pass an integer to `readln` in IR, but in your C code it accepts a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment is correct. inspire by this

```
Builder.CreateLoad(Builder.CreateIntToPtr(Value,Type::getInt32PtrTy(TheContext)), "ptr");
Builder.CreateIntToPtr(Value,Type::getInt32PtrTy(TheContext));
```